# getValue in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sort of new to Java. Get the basics and what not but still have trouble with basic code. Anyways I wrote this code but have one error as I don't know how to put this in my code. Can someone explain to me how to getValue or how to apply this in my code? It could be simple but I'm so lost as to get this working.

```
    class ArrayPar
     {
      private long[] theArray;
      private int nElems;

    public ArrayPar(int max)
      {
       theArray = new long[max];
       nElems = 0;
      }

    public void insert(long value)
       { 
         theArray[nElems] = value;
         nElems++;
       }
    public int size()
      {
      return nElems;
      }

    public void display()

    {

    System.out.print("A=");

    for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)

    System.out.print(theArray[j] + " ");

    System.out.println("");

    }

    public int partitionIt(int left, int right, long pivot)
           {
           int leftPtr = left - 1;       
           int rightPtr = right + 1;        
           while(true)
              {
              while(leftPtr < right &&     
                    theArray[++leftPtr] < pivot)
                 ;  // (nop)

              while(rightPtr > left &&      
                    theArray[--rightPtr] > pivot)
                 ;  // (nop)
              if(leftPtr >= rightPtr)       
                 break;                     
              else                          
                 swap(leftPtr, rightPtr);    
              }  // end while(true)
           return leftPtr;                   
           }  // end partitionIt()

    public int partitionIt2(int left, int right)
    {
       long pivot = theArray[nElems-1];
       int leftPtr = left - 1;
       int rightPtr = right + 1;

   while(true)
    {
     while(leftPtr < right &&     
     theArray[++leftPtr] < pivot)


              while(rightPtr > left &&      
                    theArray[--rightPtr] > pivot)
                 ;  // (nop)
              if(leftPtr >= rightPtr)       
                 break;                     
              else                          
                 swap(leftPtr, rightPtr);    
              }  // end while(true)
           return leftPtr;                   
           }  // end partitionIt()

    public void swap(int dex1, int dex2) 
    {

    long temp;
    temp = theArray[dex1];
    theArray[dex1] = theArray[dex2];
    theArray[dex2] = temp;
     }
       }

    class PartitionApp

    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
          {
          int maxSize = 10;              // array size
          ArrayPar arr;                 // reference to array
          arr = new ArrayPar(maxSize);  // create the array

          for(int j=0; j<maxSize; j++)  // fill array with
             {                          // random numbers
             long n = (int)(java.lang.Math.random()*99);
             arr.insert(n);
             }
          arr.display();                // display original array
                                        // partition the array
          int partition = arr.partitionIt2(0, maxSize-1);

          System.out.println("Partition is at index " + partition +
                          ", pivot=" + (arr.getValue(partition)) );
          arr.display();                // display partitioned array
          }  // end main()
       }  // end class PartitionApp
```

ERROR

```
(arr.getValue(partition)) );
    ^
  symbol:   method getValue(int)
  location: variable arr of type ArrayPar
1 error
```

Comment: I assume that the `getValue` method should be returning value in the `theArray` at the specified position, `public long getValue(int i) { return theArray[i]; }`

Comment: `getValue(int)` method doesn't exists in `ArrayPar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `getValue(int)` to `ArrayPar`. That might look something like,

```
public long getValue(int x) {
    return theArray[x];
}
```